# 301 redirects(.htaccess) - http to https + www to non-www + 'index.php' to '/'

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have gone through a lot of articles on 301 redirects(.htaccess), but haven't found any which could help on all 3 redirects as I mentioned in the title of this question (http to https + www to non-www + 'index.php' to '/').

What I have tried so far(but unable to achieve the desired result):

`.htaccess file`

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect http to https plus www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
#redirect /index.php to /
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

This works fine, only when it comes to `http` to `https`, but all three redirects don't work at once, If I try different-different solutions, I get `Error Too many redirects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect http to https plus www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
#redirect /index.php to /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]
```

Edit :

If you are using `cloudflare` then you will need to replace the `%{HTTPS}`  variable with Cloudflare url scheme check variable `%{HTTP:CF-Visitor}` .

Replace  this line

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
```

with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"' [OR]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: That's what I did @starkeen

Comment: @RaviWadhwani Are you using Cloudflare?

Comment: Yes! I am using cloudflare.

Comment: Now I also want to remove .php from URL, I have seen a lot solutions on this, but I am afraid, If I do so, I may run into trouble with https & www redirect error. Please help! @starkeen

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^  https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php / [R=301,L]
```

The rules above will match both `https://www`  and http://www and all `http://` and force them into `https://without-wwww` and also will ignore only `https://without-www`.

last line will remove `index` in URI.

**Note:** clear browser cache the test

Comment: @RaviWadhwani did you clear browser cache ? do you have any other rules ? paste your htaccess file

Comment: Yes, I did clear cache/cookies before checking if the solutions work! I have already added htaccess file in my question!